# Kivy app with my own class crashed when I load it on kivyLauncher

Tags: python, android, kivy

I want to create my first kivy app, but when I started launch it on kivyLauncher this code just crashed. On my computer this app work exelent, and I have no idea what can be wrong.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyBoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        n = 3
        for i in range(n):
            button = Button(text=f'Button №{i+1}')

            self.add_widget(button)


class NewApp(App):

    def build(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NewApp().run()
```

**new.kv**

```
MyBoxLayout:
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `kivyLauncher` only supports Kivy 2. Try replacing the `f-string` in your code with something simpler like:

```
button = Button(text='Button '+str(i))
```

Comment: You advice didn't work. I notice that kivyLauncher start successfully only when my own classes are written in individual `.kv` files, but the same classes that placed in `main.py` are  crash the launch.